# AWS how to allow only few incoming links to our setup

Tags: amazon-web-services

we have following setup.

1. we have webserver on nginx and behind that java server and then behind mysql db.
   in our application we allow login and then perform operation which sends some info to thirdparty endpoint and then we expect some response from them on our webserver.

we would like to restrict this with our vpn , where in only our vpn users can login, but the issue is when we expect some response from thirdparty, those are also getting blocked. we have the links which are coming to our app,  we would like to whitelist those links so that entire setup works with vpn restriction.

any advise how to achieve this?
above entire setup is on aws ec2 vms.

tried the security groups, but that only works with ips, and the incoming response sites keep sending from different different ips every few hours, so this doesnt work.